# Errors while submitting txn from cardano-serialization-lib

Tags: nami-wallet, cardano-serialization-lib

I have a working transaction in cardano-cli, but I'm having trouble constructing the same one using the serialization-lib. Does anyone know what these errors mean?? I tried looking into the typescript definitions, but the documentation isn't great.

```
""transaction submit error ShelleyTxValidationError ShelleyBasedEraAlonzo (ApplyTxError [
UtxowFailure (NonOutputSupplimentaryDatums (fromList [SafeHash \"9cbcced629edb13ecef78c9c27adfe079a9acd77b62a6693eab0134920a595b9\"]) (fromList [])),
UtxowFailure (ExtraRedeemers [RdmrPtr Spend 1]),
UtxowFailure (WrappedShelleyEraFailure (MissingScriptWitnessesUTXOW (fromList [ScriptHash \"25da22dfd99bf874e59d74c304a1d28e921310327c3e4d6960123f2e\"]))),
UtxowFailure (WrappedShelleyEraFailure (UtxoFailure (UtxosFailure (CollectErrors [NoWitness (ScriptHash \"25da22dfd99bf874e59d74c304a1d28e921310327c3e4d6960123f2e\")]))))])""
```

See on [Github](https://github.com/Emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib/issues/241)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have the exact same issue

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem.

Comment: Trying removing the first 6 bytes from your plutus hex :)

Answer (score 1):

how you've been building out your transaction? Have you tried using `TransactionBuilder`?

It seems like you haven't signed your transaction before you tried to send it to the network.

Here's a [link](https://github.com/Emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib/blob/master/doc/getting-started/generating-transactions.md) to the cardano-serialization-lib doc where they describe how to build transaction using `TransactionBuilder`.

Also, you can take a look in the spacebudz repo in the `initTx` method where the `TransactionBuilder` is used.

Here's a [link](https://github.com/pyropy/spacebudz-1/blob/main/src/cardano/market/index.js#L275) to the method